# How to read command output and use it silently on a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, wifi

I'm new on bash. I want to write a script which will run `iwconfig` command the output should show me my wlan* mode is Managed or Monitor?
I had tried this like following but it is not working and runs the command output. I just need to `echo` which mode is it.

```
IWCONFIG_LOG="$(iwconfig)"
if [[ "$IWCONFIG_LOG" == *Mode:Managed* ]]; then
  echo "Managed"
elif [[ "$IWCONFIG_LOG" == *Mode:Monitor* ]]; then
  echo "Monitor Mode"
fi
```

Comment: Please read [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Comment: Can you try with `=~` instead of `==` inside `if` conditions, like this: `if [[ "$IWCONFIG_LOG" =~ Mode:Managed ]]; then...` ?

Comment: I don't know how the standard output of iwconfig looks like, but the condition of your test does necessarily not look wrong to me. Doesn't `set -x` reveal anything?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to use Bash (not sh) in order to get this accomplish.
So, try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
IWCONFIG_LOG="$((iwconfig | grep Mode) 2> /dev/null)"
if [[ $IWCONFIG_LOG == *"Mode:Managed"* ]]; then
  echo "Managed"
elif [[ $IWCONFIG_LOG == *"Mode:Monitor"* ]]; then
  echo "Monitor Mode"
fi
```

Save it as a file and *chmod 755* it to make it executable or execute it using "**bash**" instead "**sh**".
There are several modes, not only *Managed* or *Monitor*, so seems you only want to detect one of these two.
To see all available modes read `man iwconfig`

Answer (score 0):

Since `iwconfig` writes also to standard error:

```
if [[ $(iwconfig 2>/dev/null | grep "Managed") ]]; then
    echo "Managed"
else
    echo "Monitor"
fi
```

or, as pointed out by @choroba in comments:

```
if iwconfig 2>/dev/null | grep -q Managed ; then
    echo "Managed"
else
    echo "Monitor"
fi
```

Comment: `if iwconfig 2>/dev/null | grep -q Managed ; then`

Comment: I dont have `iwconfig` to test with and couldn't find the answer to this in the man page but - are you sure the text the OPs interested in isn't part of what goes to stderr? If so, then `2>&1` would be required instead of `2>/dev/null`.

Comment: Thanks. It's perfect. Now I am understanding some things.

Comment: I don't think this is a correct approach. What if iwconfig outputs neither "Managed" nor "Monitor" ?